# implemention of login using UserDetails in Spring Security does not work

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a simple Spring Boot 2.xx App with Spring Data JPA MySQL, I have to secure this web app using Spring Security (especially Java config) in this regard I found plenty of resources online to get the Job done but **in vain**, some examples were too complex to understand and other examples never worked my on side. I came up with this [secure-spring-demo](https://github.com/arshadalisoomro/secure-spring-demo), which is also not working. some code snips are

WebSecurityConfig class is

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login*", "/register", "/").anonymous()
                .antMatchers("/secure/*").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN").anyRequest().authenticated()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .and()
                .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

and UserDetailsServiceImpl class is

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public UserDetailsServiceImpl(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userService.findByUserEmail(s);
        if (user == null){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User with " + s + " not found!");
        }

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                user.getUserEmail(), user.getUserPassword(), user.getRoles());
    }
}
```

the controller is

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private RoleService roleService;

    @Autowired
    private SecurityService securityService;

    //Omitting other mappings

    @GetMapping(value = "/login")
    public String getLogin(Model model,
                           @RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error){
        if (null != error && error.equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
            model.addAttribute("loginError", "Unable to Login");
        }
        return "login";
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/login")
    public String postLogin(@RequestParam(value = "userEmail") String userEmail,
                              @RequestParam(value = "userPassword") String userPassword){
        logger.debug(userEmail + " and " + userPassword );
        boolean loginResult = securityService.login(userEmail, userPassword);
        return (loginResult ? "redirect:/secure/home" : "redirect:/login?error=true");
    }

}
```

with this all the user is not able to login with correct credentials.

Comment: @kj007 Not getting any error but always falling in to "redirect:/login?error=true".

Comment: @aka-one thanks for your time, but this example uses `inMemoryAuthentication`, what I want to implement is UserDetailsService way of login.

Comment: @ArshadAli can you please update http security as described in my answer , let me know if you still face issue..

Comment: @ArshadAli Why do you implement `postLogin`? That is not neccessary, Spring Security will handle it by itself. Remove this method.

Comment: @ArshadAli If you are redirected to `/login?error=true` your username or password is wrong. Is your `UserDetailsServiceImpl` used?

Comment: @Arshad Ali: And? Add a breakpoint in your `UserDetailsServiceImpl` and look if it is hit and what your service returns.

Answer (score 2):

Main problem I was found in your code was not passing "username" and "password" properties from thymeleaf template as it should match with exact credentials properties to order to authenticate object..so your login form will be like this:

```html
 <form th:method="post" th:action="@{/login}" enctype="utf8">
  <input th:type="email" name="username" placeholder="Email" required="">
  <input th:type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="">
  <button th:type="submit" name="submit"> Login </button>
  <span>You Have No Account? <a th:href="@{/register}"> Create An Account</a></span>
 </form>
```

2. as params are changed so you also need to change controller properties:

   ```
   @PostMapping(value = "/login")
   public String postLogin(@RequestParam(value = "username") String userEmail,
                             @RequestParam(value = "password") String userPassword){
       logger.debug(userEmail + " and " + userPassword );
       boolean loginResult = securityService.login(userEmail, userPassword);
       return (loginResult ? "redirect:/secure/home" : "redirect:/login?error=true");
   }
   ```

Comment: I was already able to access /login and /register paths, but the issue is with credentials, it is not letting the user with correct credentials to login

Comment: sure, its https://github.com/arshadalisoomro/secure-spring-demo right??

Comment: Yes, it is the demo!

Comment: you have to apply a filter where you will set authentication detail as currently user name is blank when it go to check loadUser in user detail service, let me add that and push to git..

Comment: I have updated  answer for main problem, please check now userload service is loading fine.. but now still I am seeing I am seeing error:  Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
 its not calling your post /login controller so still checking..

Answer (score 0):

Main Cause, Because you want to custom method handle login of spring security but you again set name of the custom method which has name same with method login default of spring security. So Web will call login method of spring but No call your method custom.

In this case, You must to convert to name different with method name of spring login default If you want to custom method login of spring security. This is your suggest I can follow.

I edit "login" to loginCustom in file login.html

[image: login.xml]

And In UserController.java, I edit to "/loginCustom"
[image]